# Ubuntu 22.04 - Kernel Panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

Eror msg:  Kernel Panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel.

I installed Ubuntu MATE 22.04, successfully. However once I cold or warm boot, the system fails to do so and gives the above message. Re-installation of same OS gives the same result as does installing recent releases of Kali and Debian.

I have re-formatted EFI, /Boot and / with each re-install.

What do I do?

equip
HP h8-1435/2AD5, BIOS 8.11 10/23/2012
Kingston SSD UV500

partitions
sda1  EFI    135mb
sda2  /Boot  400mb
sda4  /      250gb
sda3  /Home  330gb

Comment: I am getting the same Kernel Panic with Ubuntu Live Server 22.10. I have downloaded the ISO and the Sha check is fine. When I burn the ISO using Rufus, it can't get past the GRUB Loader. When I burn the ISO using balanaEtcher I get the Kernel Panic above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, and its consistently booting properly.

I have 4 partitions: Home, Root, Boot and EFI. I realized that my Boot was too small, so I enlarged it from 400mb to 1024mb. I've been booting successfully ever since. Currently the partition uses 265mb with 758mb free.

Apparently Ubuntu keeps some of the old Boot files and needed more space than was available.

I hope this helps.